# Finding polynomial generators in a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

$S$ is a subspace $S= \{p\in P_3|~\text{$i\in\Bbb C$ is root of $p$}\}$.

So the question at hand is how do you find the system of generators for the subspace knowing that $x$ is $p$'s divisor? Furthermore, How do you find all $p \in \mathrm{gen}\{x^2, x, 1/2\}$ ?

Comment: I edited your tex code. Let me know/unedit if it doesn’t fit with your intentions. What is $x$? Which base field are you considering, $ℝ$, $ℂ$? Does $\mathrm{gen} A$ denote the span of $A$ for that base field? Is $P_3$ the space of polynomials of the degree (exactly) $3$ over the base field? You should clarify.

Comment: Aw heck, the question is in Spanish and that's all it says. I can see how it lacks information.